# Horizontal to Vertical Pattern

Tags: python

Horizontal to Vertical Pattern

The program must accept a string matrix of size NxN as the input. The
program must print the desired pattern as shown in the Example
Input/Output section.

Boundary Condition(s):
1 <= N <= 50
1 <= Length of each string <= 25

Input Format:
The first line contains N.
The next N lines, each containing N string values separated by a space.

Output Format:
The lines containing the desired pattern as shown in the Example
Input/Output section.

```
Example Input/Output 1:
Input:
2
hi how
are u

Output:
h h
i o
* w
a *
r u
e *

Example Input/Output 2:
Input:
3
dog rabbit monkey
soldier king queen
red green yellow

Output:
d r m
o a o
g b n
* b k
s i e
o t y
l * *
d k q
i i u
e n e
r g e
* * n
r g *
e r y
d e e
* e l
* n l
* * o
* * w
```

my code

```
n=int(input())
l=[list(map(int,input(),split()))[:n] for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for k in range(len(max(l[i],key=len))):
        for j in range(n):
            try:
               print(l[i][j][k],end=' ')
            except IndexError:
                  print('*',end=' ')
        print()
```

```
output for my code:
2
hi how
are u
h h 
i o 
* w 
a u 
r * 
e *
```

how to order the asterik correctly as per pattern

Comment: What have you done to debug this yourself?

Comment: How does this `l=[list(map(int,input(),split()))[:n] for i in range(n)]` make sense: it's neither valid Python, nor does the input require casting into `int`?

Answer (score 2):

For the input reading use:

```py
n = int(input())
word_lists = [input().split() for _ in range(n)]
```

And then apply `zip`:

```py
strings, max_length = [], 0
for words in zip(*word_lists):
    strings.append("*".join(words))
    max_length = max(len(strings[-1]), max_length)
strings = (string + "*" * (max_length - len(string)) for string in strings)
for chars in zip(*strings):
    print(*chars)
```

Or, much simpler, use `zip_longest` from the standard library module `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

strings = ("*".join(words) for words in zip(*word_lists))
for chars in zip_longest(*strings, fillvalue="*"):
    print(*chars)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect nor the most compact but it should do the trick for you to simplify afterwards.
For the spaces into `*` I used [`replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp), this should fix your issues I hope.

```py
## Get number of inputs
input_count = int(input())
if input_count <= 0:
    print("Input must be an integer superior or equal to 1")
    exit(1)

## Get the other inputs
input_list = []
for i in range(input_count):
    input_list.append(input())

## Check if the inputs are correct (exact size and word count)
for i in range(1, len(input_list)):
    if len(input_list[i - 1]) != len(input_list[i]):
        print(f"Inputs are not of the same size: '{input_list[i - 1]}', {len(input_list[i - 1])} | '{input_list[i]}', {len(input_list[i])}")
        exit(1)
    elif len(input_list[i - 1].split(" ")) != len(input_list[i].split(" ")):
        print(f"Inputs do not have the same word count: '{input_list[i - 1]}', {len(input_list[i - 1].split(' '))} | '{input_list[i]}', {len(input_list[i].split(' '))}")
        exit(1)

## Replace ' ' to '*'
result_list = []
for string in input_list:
    result_list.append(string.replace(" ", "*"))

## Print results
for i in range(len(input_list[0])):
    for j in range(1, input_count):
        print(f"{result_list[j- 1][i]} {result_list[j][i]}")
```

(This being my first time answering an issue, please comment any mistakes I may have made)

Comment: I don't think this does what the question asks: the check `len(input_list[i - 1]) != len(input_list[i])` is no requirement, look a the first example?